# RegEx site address w/path

Tags: regex

Please help make a regular expression to sites with or without paths,
for example:

```
http://www.sitename.domain/dir/dir2/file.jpg
www.sitename.domain/dir/file.jpg
sub.sitename.domain/dir/dir2/file.jpg
site.do/file.pjg
https://go.do/dir/file.png
ftp://site.dom/file.blah_blah
```

exact domains are not important

Comment: Good day to you too! A bit more info, please: Do you want to find these URLs within longer pieces of text, or do your strings contain exactly one URL and nothing more? Any restrictions on what you want to match/not match?

Comment: I'm used the text and I need to find this urls in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match a URL using regex, you could use this:

```
^(((https?)|(ftp)):\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$
```

You can find some description on http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/

Comment: Excuse me, but u try this regex on my example? it's not work with "Www" and other path

Comment: yeah, i tried each and every input string of yours, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: i just updated brackets in the regex, please try and check if it works for you.

Comment: No problem :)
Please do not forget to mark it as answer if it satisfies your needs :)